# How to set two different formatting styles and map them to different shortcuts in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, formatting

Every time I open a file in Eclipse, I want to format the source code to Allman-style indentation. Every time I save, it should format to the dictated style in the office.

I'm OK with doing this manually and having two hot-keys for it:

- Ctrl-Alt-PgUp: my way
- Ctrl-Alt-PgDown: high way

The hot key option is good because then I get to verify all is well instead of it happening invisibly behind the scenes.

However, Eclipse only has a single format option. What I need is two formatting styles and map them each to a shortcut key. Is that possible, and if so, how?

Comment: I wonder if this is better accomplished through hooks in your version control system. Set Eclipse up the way *you* want it, but then force your VCS to commit code the way your team wants it. What VCS are you using?

Comment: If you all have your own formatting styles set in Eclipse, why does it matter what it looks like in the repository?  Everyone who loads it will automatically end up with code that looks good to them.

Comment: @James: Imagine this: A edits, saves in style 1 and commits. B edits, saves in style 2 and commits. Result: The diff is littered with irrelevant but very distracting whitespaces changes. The code in the repo should be formatted in exactly one way.

Comment: @delnan You're right. If only we had a way to abstract style from the repository.

Comment: @James: Well, running all code through an automated formatter in a pre-commit hook seems to be the standard (and it seems to work pretty well).

Comment: Is there a scripting language or class I could drop into Eclipse that would tell Eclipse to switch to another formatting profile and then format? That way I could have two of those scripts and create shortcuts for each...

Comment: Isn't the primary difference with Allman and K&R simply where you put the opening braces?

Answer (score 8):

Unfortunately, Eclipse JDT UI does not support applying different code formatters yet.

There's [bug no 45423](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=45423), which is intended to resolve this. As long as that bug remains unfixed, the best workaround would be applying a formatter in a commit hook as each project is associated with it's own formatter; you cannot even choose a different formatter to apply on the file save action (Preferences -> Java -> Editor -> Save Actions). Honestly, I don't think shortcut keys would even work.

Also, it might be worth investigating the use of the [Questoid Code Formatter](http://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/questoid-code-formatter), which appears to be the closest (or only) plugin to support your need. I haven't attempted using it; I've only read the description from Eclipse Marketplace.